# sort mongodb documents by timestamp (in desc order)

Tags: python, mongodb, timestamp

I have a bunch of documents in mongodb and all have a timestamp field with timestamp stored as "1404008160". I want to sort all docs in this collection by desc order. I do it by:

```
sort = [('timestamp', DESCENDING)]
collection.find(limit=10).sort(sort)
```

However, I don't get results sorted by timestamp in desc order. I am thinking it's because timestamp is being treated as an int field. Is there a work around this without changing data type of timestamp field. I already have a lot of data in this collection so don't want to go through the hassle of import/export, etc.

Also - I want to keep the load for sorting to mongodb rather than doing it programmatically in python.

To be clear: Timestamp does not indicate when the document was created and it is stored as string (e.g. "1404217646").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you have imported the constants that would otherwise be represented as `pymongo.DESCENDING`. But really that is just a constant for `-1` to make reading easier. As an `int` should not matter as the values should order that way. Possibly are these actually strings? Meaning, do those quotes `""` appear when you look at the data in the shell?

Comment: yes - the quotes do appears - so timestamp is stored as string.. and I am looking for a workaround without changing data type of this field in all the existing docs

Comment: There really isn't a workaround. Even as strings this should still sort correctly as the values are lexical. Unless of course some are numbers and some are strings, which will cause a problem. If you are looking for a way for MongoDB to "cast" values, then that is not going to happen, outside of string hackery, but that would not be efficient. You really need to change the type. Best form is as a BSON date, which just internally stores the timestamp value, but will automatically cast as dates in your program.

Comment: well - i ended up reconstructing all docs

Answer (score 40):

Assuming your timestamp indicates when the document was created, [you can use `_id` instead](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#convert-an-objectid-into-a-timestamp).

`_id` ObjectId in mongo stores your timestamp. Try the following:

```
sort = {'_id': -1}
collection.find({}, limit=10).sort(sort)
```

If you still want to sort by your custom `timestamp` field, the following should work:

```
sort = {'timestamp': -1}
collection.find({}, limit=10).sort(sort)
```

Note that this is assuming all of your `timestamp` fields are of the same type (`string`, `int`)

Comment: Timestamp does not indicate when the document was created - so the above won't work. Aren't the two solutions same?

Comment: You're right - fixed. The second solution works? If not you may need to map your data to the same type. Theres a quick way for that

Comment: The second solution also doesn't work as timestamp is stored as a string. I have my sort var implemented as such: [('timestamp', -1)]. 
Anyway, I would be interested in knowing how can I "map data to the same type." The final solution, I am thinking, will be to reconstruct docs so all have timestamp stored in bson date format.

Comment: Depending on how your string is formatted, sorting can still work. One example is if the format is a variation of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` where HH is in the range of [00, 23].

Comment: I follow the same step but it returns TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of a list,
```
>>> for x in post.find():
...     print(x['timestamp'])
...
Timestamp(1591790235, 1)
Timestamp(1591790259, 1)
Timestamp(1591790271, 1)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can sort your collection in descending order by using `sort( { 'timestamp': -1 } )`.Your query will be like this

```
collection.find().sort( { 'timestamp': -1 } ).limit(10)
```

If you have sql knowledge, you can compare both queries in the following link

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: It should be noted that even though this works since it is a single field your are sorting by it is not the best way to do it in python since dicts are unordered

Comment: @Sammaye, I thought that there are multiple filed's and timestamp is a common field in the collection.

Comment: There are multiple fields in the documents themselves but within the sort specification you are only supplying one field.

Comment: Isn't the suggested solution same as: collection.find(limit=10).sort( { 'timestamp': -1 } )